# Shouldn't the questions about a third party plugin whose developer is an active member/moderator be allowed?

Tags: discussion, extensions, magento

I recently asked a question regarding ULTIMATE MODULE CREATOR [How to create a frontend form using Ultimate Module Creator](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111268/how-to-create-a-frontend-form-using-ultimate-module-creator).

I am well aware regarding the guidelines of magento stackexchange, however I decided to ask the question as the developer of the module is one of the moderator of the website, so there is an every possibility for getting a correct and accurate answer for it.

Also, as ULTIMATE MODULE CREATOR is a very useful module giving its support on stackexchange will be helpful for the community.

Comment: This will answer your question http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73/questions-about-extensions?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they should not be allowed.
If the third party module developer is active there is a high chance he/she will answer your question if you contact him/her for support.
Allowing question as the one you described opens a dangerous door.
Someone may be active today but not next week.

In your particular case, I was the developer in question, I also closed the question for reasons stated above, but I still answered because it took me 1 minute to do it and I wanted you to get the answer fast so you won't send me an e-mail with the same question :).

I will stop answering these questions from now on, in order not to encourage this type of questions.

Comment: +1 for the decision to "not answer". However as you mentioned, it is a better way to avoid huge "inbox" :)

Comment: Thanks Understood :)